# Phonemic shift: voiced pharyngeal fricative to velar nasal

Tags: phonetics

In most Semitic language, one of the phonemes is a voiced pharyngeal fricative (ע in Hebrew and ع in Arabic). However, in some dialects of Hebrew, namely Spanish-Portuguese, Dutch Ashkenazi, and Italian, the letter ע has shifted from a voiced pharyngeal fricative to velar nasal phoneme. How could these phonemes shift so drastically?

Comment: Why shouldn't they? Labialised velar stops (/kw/ etc) have shifted to labial stops (/p/) on at least three separate occasions in the development of Indo-European languages, and these are much less similar acoustically than the ones you mention. similarly, interdental fricatives have shifted to labiodental ones at several times and places.

Comment: It was proposed to use ע in phonetic script for the velar nasal by you'll never guess who -- https://books.google.com/books?id=HVarBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=isaac+newton+velar+nasal&source=bl&ots=7LetyOB3l0&sig=Lxn2A5Rg9rgI_2buRo6WFq9YPiY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI_ZWeqJCEyQIVAVKICh1_kgFD#v=onepage&q=isaac%20newton%20velar%20nasal&f=false

Comment: @ColinFine kW and p are both stops, though. The striking fact about the Hebrew change above isn't the addition of nasalization, but the conversion of a fricative into a nasal stop (which is what I understood by "velar nasal" in the original question) with a different place of articulation. For example, did the nasalization "swallow up" the pharyngeal in this case, along the lines of ʕ > ʕŋ > ŋ, or similar?

Answer (score 6):

This is an instance of [rhinoglottophilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhinoglottophilia), related to antiresonances and the acoustic structure of these sounds. A parallel case is the change of *h* to *ŋ* in the Luyia Bantu language Nyole.

Answer (score 0):

The word "dialect" is misleading in this context. We are talking not about spoken languages, but about reading conventions of a liturgical language, in the same way that (for example) the French liturgical pronunciation of Latin is not a dialect of Latin but a reading convention. In the case of Hebrew, the unfamiliar sounds of the sacred language are replaced by sounds familiar to the speakers of the colloquial language.